# war deployment init method

Tags: java, servlets, war

i am deploying an war file (consists of jpa and servlet stuff) on glassfish (the most recent one)

I wanna insert/check some data right after i deploy my war file via JPA.

What/Which class to override what/which method?

I am currently overriding servlet's init method. It is only called when I request that servlet from my browser. I want it to be invoked when the war is deployed right after. Injections has to be gone through in all servlets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ServletContextListener`. If you want to use Servlet's `init()` then make sure you specify [load-on-startup](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/load-on-startup-servlet-webxml-example.html)

Comment: thnx! i totally forgot those nasty listeners. i must have been trying to forget them.